# Up-counter in Javascript from a date

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm new here and never worked with JavaScript.
So maybe you can help me a little bit.
I wanna make an Up-counter that counts up from a date.
Everything works fine but I want to add month to the counter. Here is the Code:

```js
window.onload=function() {
  // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
  upTime('jan,01,2013,00:00:00'); // ****** Change this line!
};
function upTime(countTo) {
  now = new Date();
  countTo = new Date(countTo);
  difference = (now-countTo);
  days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
  years = Math.floor(days / 365);
  if (years > 1){ days = days - (years * 365)}
  hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
  mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
  secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
  document.getElementById('years').firstChild.nodeValue = years;
  document.getElementById('days').firstChild.nodeValue = days;
  document.getElementById('hours').firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
  document.getElementById('minutes').firstChild.nodeValue = mins;
  document.getElementById('seconds').firstChild.nodeValue = secs;

  clearTimeout(upTime.to);
  upTime.to=setTimeout(function(){ upTime(countTo); },1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="countup">
  It's been
  <p id="years">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefYears">years</p>
  <p id="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">days</p>
  <p id="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">hours</p>
  <p id="minutes">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefMinutes">minutes</p>
  <p id="seconds">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefSeconds">second</p>
</div>
```

Maybe you can help me and I am trying to understand.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your script cannot easily and certainly not accurately get months added

Have a look at this.

I have not fully tested it so it might need some tweaking.

When it works it should be more accurate than yours

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
  upTime('jan,16,2013,19:30:00'); // ****** Change this line!
};

function upTime(countTo) {
  var now = new Date(), countTo = new Date(countTo),
    years  = now.getFullYear()-countTo.getFullYear(),     
    months = now.getMonth()   -countTo.getMonth(),
    days   = now.getDate()    -countTo.getDate(), 
    hours  = now.getHours()   -countTo.getHours(),
    mins   = now.getMinutes() -countTo.getMinutes(),    
    secs   = now.getSeconds() -countTo.getSeconds();    
  if (months<0) {
    years--;
    months += 12;
  }
  if (days<0) {
    months--;
    var daysOfMonth = new Date(now.getTime())
    daysOfMonth.setMonth(now.getMonth()+1)
    daysOfMonth.setDate(0);
    days+=daysOfMonth.getDate();
  }
  if (hours<0) {
    days--;
    hours+=24;
  }
  if (mins<0) {
    hours--;
    mins+=60;
  }
  if (secs<0) {
    mins--;
    secs+=60;
  }
  if (months<0) months = 0;
  

  document.getElementById('years'  ).innerHTML = years;
  document.getElementById('months' ).innerHTML = months;
  document.getElementById('days'   ).innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById('hours'  ).innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = mins;
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = secs;

  clearTimeout(upTime.to);
  upTime.to = setTimeout(function() {
    upTime(countTo);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="countup">
  It's been
  <p id="years">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefYears">years</p>
  <p id="months">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefMonths">months</p>
  <p id="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">days</p>
  <p id="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">hours</p>
  <p id="minutes">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefMinutes">minutes</p>
  <p id="seconds">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefSeconds">seconds</p>
</div>
```